# Detect focus on select box to change class/style in surrounding DIV

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where I need to surround a select box with a div. That select box is transparent and therefore the styles, including focus styles, need to occur on the surrounding div. I have been playing with the idea of detecting if the select box is focused and if so add a class. But nothing seems to work... I have also used scripts with .is :focus which work well in most browsers but not in IE and specifically IE8, which unfortunately I have to support. Can anyone help?

```
 <div class="styled-select">
<select id="Title" name="Title" required autofocus="autofocus">
     <option value="" selected=yes> Title </option>
     <option value="Ms" > Ms </option>
    <option value="Mrs" > Mrs </option>
 </select>
</div>    

var select = $('select:focus');    

$(select).each(function(){
      $('.styled-select').addClass('focus');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to change each to focusin :

```
 $('#Title').focusin(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass('focus');
  });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQP9M/)

Comment: Thanks. This works well in Firefox, but this does not appear to work in ie8 however

Comment: Oops...edit there was a conflicting JS that was stopping it from working. Seems like all is good. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the other issue I have is that it should already be in focus with autofocus set, but this seems not to happen. The focus is not set until a user clicks on it...?

Comment: if you wish to add focus to elements who has autofocus , here is how you should do it :
 
`$('[autofocus="autofocus"]').focus(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass('focus');
  });`

Comment: Hmm...not sure what I am doing wrong, but it appears not to work: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnexH/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I should add a click event, detect the focus that doesn't seems to work on a select.
the .focus could be set by click, and removed by change event, but the change event is also a click, so it should looks like :

```
$("#Title").click(function () {
    if ($('.styled-select').hasClass('focus')) {
        $('.styled-select').removeClass('focus');
    } else {
        $('.styled-select').addClass('focus');
    }
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W5sYv/1/

Comment: Thanks, this also works for me..I hadn't thought of the click event. Thansk!